# Headphones stopped working on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

my headphones stopped working one day, using laptop dell precision m4800.
I think i have made before

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

then after reboot it died.
Sound is working normally on speakers.
Have checked some posts on forum which were describing to reset pulseaudio setting to default etc. None of those help.

output of lspci -v | grep -i audio

```
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Dell Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Dell 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller
```

into /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf also added

```
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-pcsp index=-2
alias snd-card-0 snd-hda-intel
alias sound-slot-0 snd-hda-intel
options snd-hda-intel model=auto
```

as someone mentioned and didnt help.

output of aplay -l

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3226 Analog [ALC3226 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Anyone could give me a hint what should i do? because seems like nothing helps?

thank you

Comment: Have you made sure the right audio channel (not sure if this is the right word) is used? My pulseaudio sometimes changes it and I have to change it back in the "Playback" tab of pavucontrol. Another problem I often faced was one channel set to mute in the "Output Devices" tab.

Comment: yes, i was checking, it shows that headphones are plugged.